# Liquibase - Spring Data : OneToOne relationship to self entity doesn't work

Tags: java, spring-data, liquibase

I have an entity :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "society")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
public class Society implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
    private String name;
```

I would like to add a reference to self, something like :

```
@OneToOne
private Society parentSociety
```

When I run `liquibase:diff`, liquibase doesn't notice the change and doesn't create a changelog file for this new attribute of my entity.

How could I do to make this work?

Comment: How you are running liquibase:diff, are you using liquibase-hibernate extension?

Comment: I am just running liquibase:diff from Maven. I don't know about liquibase-hibernate extension

Answer (score 0):

According to http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/maven/maven_diff.html liquibase:diff generates diff between two databases, not between database and Hibernate mappings as you expected.

Answer (score 0):

The **liquibase:diff** command generates a difference between two specified databases. You can configure for generate diff between a database and entities, but first you need configured the pom.xml and the liquibase.properties.
For the pom configuration you need the liquibase-hibernate dependency. I recommend that you follow this tutorial, its very simple and work's:

http://www.baeldung.com/liquibase-refactor-schema-of-java-app

When you change one entity and run the liquibase:diff command don't remmember the liquibase workflow:

> Modify your JPA entity (add a field, a relationship, etc.) Compile your application (this works on the compiled Java code, so don't forget to compile!) Run mvn liquibase:diff (or mvn compile liquibase:diff to compile before) A new "change log" is created in your src/main/resources/config/liquibase/changelog directory Review this change log and add it to your src/main/resources/config/liquibase/master.xml file, so it is applied the next time you run your application If you use Gradle instead of Maven, you can use the same workflow by running ./gradlew liquibaseDiffChangelog, and change the database configuration in liquibase.gradle if required.

So, if you are using maven after a change in Entity class you need compile again... just execute: **clean install**, after this you can execute liquibase:diff for generate changeSet in you liquibase-diff.xml file